# `Routing` folder not present inside `Drupal\Core\`

Tags: 8, hooks

I am trying to port a module from D7 to D8.

Since `hook_help()` uses routes instead of paths in D8, so the line `use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;` is added at the beginning of the code as mentioned on [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2250345) page.

But the thing is that no folder named `routing` exists inside my `Drupal\Core\`.

Questions.

1. Am I supposed to add that folder myself?
2. How will I configure
       `RouteMatchInterface` file.

Comment: There is no configuration in or for `RouteMatchInterface`. It is an interface. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you aren't supposed to add any directories: Drupal already comes with the [core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteMatchInterface.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Routing%21RouteMatchInterface.php/8.2.x) file containing the PHP interface you are trying to use.

There isn't anything you need to config: Just use the object passed as second parameter to [`hook_help()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21help%21help.api.php/function/hook_help/8.2.x). Drupal core's implementations of `hook_help()` don't usually use that parameter, but [`system_help()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_help/8.2.x) does use it.

```
case 'system.theme_settings_theme':
  $theme_list = \Drupal::service('theme_handler')->listInfo();
  $theme = $theme_list[$route_match->getParameter('theme')];
  return '<p>' . t('These options control the display settings for the %name theme. When your site is displayed using this theme, these settings will be used.', array('%name' => $theme->info['name'])) . '</p>';
```

`$route_match` is just an object that allows you to understand exactly for which page the help text is being generated. In the code I shown, it allows to understand exactly for which theme the settings page is shown. system.theme_settings_theme (the value for the first parameter) just tells you the page is the theme settings page (served on /admin/appearance/settings/{theme}), but the exact page could be /admin/appearance/settings/bartik, /admin/appearance/settings/stark, or /admin/appearance/settings/seven (just using some of the themes Drupal core comes with as examples).

Using `RouteMatchInterface::getParameter()`, or `RouteMatchInterface::getRawParameter()`, is what you normally do with the second parameter passed to `hook_help()`. The route name is already passed as first parameter, so `RouteMatchInterface::getRouteName()` is not providing anything that you don't already have. Eventually, you could get the [`Route`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21routing%21Route.php/class/Route/8.2.x) object associated with the page, but I cannot think of any case where that is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

That is the namespace. It's actual location in the file system is `/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing`. The autoloader knows where to look via the namespace.